# Issue: Salesforce UI, Developer Console and Eclipse IDE shows different code coverage for the same class. Is anyone experienced this?

Tags: developer-console, code-coverage

This is very much confusing and hard to believe which one is valid. Below screen shot describes the issue as the code coverage for one of the class "OpenDocumentsController" showing 100% (179/179) in Salesforce UI. And the same class the test coverage displayed as 100% (208/208) in developer console. Again, eclipse shown me different coverage which is 47%. Any suggestions? Am i doing anything wrong here?

This above class totally contains 750 lines of code.

**Screen 1:**

[image]

**Screen 2:**
[image]

**Screen 3:**
[image]

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/why-are-code-coverage-results-different-in-ide-and-developer-console

Comment: Thanks @sf.dev. I will take a look on this. Meanwhile, should i remove this post or keep this one? Please advice.